# How to remove text and number from row in Excel, but keep the numbers inside brackets

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

How can I remove all unwanted characters from a row, and keep only the numbers that are inside the brackets, using Excel?
I have a code to remove all text, but still the numbers showed outside de brackets can not be removed.

If I split in column, separating by space after remove all the text, still I cant have the rows in order, because since I cant remove all the number more unwanted columns will be created.
Thank you for your help!

[Example of the desired work and the data that I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4txdK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`FILTERXML()` may give you desired output. Try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"[","</s><s>"),"]","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.]"))
```

More about [FILTERXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) here by JvdV.

[image]